# Is it possible to get unique file descriptors from accept

Tags: c, server, client

I am trying to implement a half sync, half async server. On the server side the requests should be read into a queue that is managed by one thread. I then have a pool of worker threads that are waiting for something to be added to the queue so they can process the request. I am having issues with my accept() call. The accept call returns the same file descriptor number and this messes up the worker threads because they stop writing in one place and write to another. Is there a way to get accept to return unique file descriptors? Thanks for the help in advance! The code is fairly large so it would be impractical to post it all but here is the problem area. It is also worth mentioning that  the client has multiple threads making requested to the server. When I print out the new file descriptor “client socket” I can that it uses the same file descriptor number.

```
void accept_client_requests(int server_socket)
{
    int client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof client_addr;


    while ( (client_socket= accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &sin_size)) > 0 )
    {
        char fileName[BUFSIZ];
        get_file_request(client_socket, fileName); 

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
            queue[first].fileName = fileName;    
            queue[first].socket = client_socket;
            ++numInQ;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&empty); 
    }
}
```

Comment: All file descriptors in a process are unique.  Period.  Either you're closing the file descriptor and losing track of it, or your code is broken in other ways.  Hint:  it's much, much, much better to assume your code is bad than it is to assume there's something wrong with decades-old common code in operating systems with literally billions of installations worldwide.

Comment: I should that the client has multiple threads. That are sending requests. So it does actually use the same file descriptor

Comment: How do you set `first` in your code?  How do you know that you don't reuse the `queue` elements and overwrite values from different threads?  You almost certainly have at least one race condition.  And just what do you think this line of code does:  `queue[first].fileName = fileName;`?  That last one is scary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select will create new file descriptors as soon as the old one is closed